# Python, SqlAlchemy. Or_ expected 2 arguments, got 3

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have this problem with my code. When Iinsert three or more params in the body request, I get this Error "POST Error: or_ expected 2 arguments, got 3."
I can only pass one or two parameters in the body, in this case it works fine. But I don't understand where is the mistake. Can someone help me?

```
def read_uptime(logid, filteredData, dateStart, dateEnd, timeStart, timeEnd, elementsForPage, currentPage, filterUptime):
log.info(f"{logid} read_uptime: Started")

try:
    # Check Timeframe Correct
    startDateTime, endDateTime = _checkDataInput(timeStart, timeEnd, dateStart, dateEnd)

    # Create Filter
    filters = _createFilter(filteredData, startDateTime, endDateTime, filterUptime)

    # Query
    dataFiltered = uptime_model_db.query.with_entities(
        uptime_model_db.projectId.label('projectId'),
        uptime_model_db.url.label('url'),
        uptime_model_db.timeStamp.label('timeStamp'),
        uptime_model_db.uptime.label('uptime'),
        uptime_model_db.latency.label('latency')
        ).filter(*filters).paginate(per_page=int(elementsForPage + 1), page=int(currentPage), error_out=True)


    # Checking more pages
    nextPage = {
        "currentPage": currentPage,
        "totalElements": len(dataFiltered.items)
    }

    if (len(dataFiltered.items) > elementsForPage):
        nextPage["nextPage"] = True
    else:
        nextPage["nextPage"] = False


    # Format and return JSON
    return _createJson(dataFiltered.items, nextPage)

except Exception as e:
    log.error(f"{logid} read_uptime: function read_uptime returned {e}")
    raise e
```

i get in this code the mistake: "array.Filter.append(and_(uptime_model.db.porjectId == projectId, or_(*arrayUrl))"

```
def filterAppend(arrayFilter, urls, projectId, arrayUrl):
if(len(urls) == 1):
    arrayFilter.append(and_(uptime_model_db.projectId == projectId, uptime_model_db.url == urls[0]))

if(len(urls) > 1):
    for url in urls:
        arrayUrl.append(uptime_model_db.url == url)
    arrayFilter.append(and_(uptime_model_db.projectId == projectId, or_(*arrayUrl)))
```

i get in this code the mistake:
"filters.append(or_(*arrayFilter))"

```
def _createFilter(filteredData, startDateTime, endDateTime, filterUptime):

filters = []

if filteredData is not None:
    arrayFilter = []

    for data in filteredData:
        projectId = data["projectId"]
        urls = data["uptimeUrls"]
        arrayUrl = []
        
        if (len(filteredData) == 1):
            filterAppend(filters, urls, projectId, arrayUrl)

        else:
            filterAppend(arrayFilter, urls, projectId, arrayUrl)

    if(len(filteredData) > 1 or len(arrayFilter) > 1):
        filters.append(or_(*arrayFilter))



if startDateTime is not None:
    filters.append(str(startDateTime) <= uptime_model_db.timeStamp)

if startDateTime is not None:
    filters.append(str(endDateTime) >= uptime_model_db.timeStamp)

if filterUptime == "True":
    filters.append(uptime_model_db.uptime < 100)

return filters
```

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . It appears you're unpacking the entire arrayUrl or arrayFilter into or_, when it only takes 2 arguments, the two filters you want to be OR'd. In order to OR more than 2 things together, you'll need to do `or_(f1, or_(f2, f3))` I believe. This means rather than just unpacking your variable with * you need to unpack it 2 elements at a time in a loop and build up your filter one or_ at a time. It seems that's your idea in create_filter, but both arrayUrls and arrayFilter can be >2 so * won't just work without extra checks.

Comment: I believe your mistake may have been here: rather than appending to filters, `filters = or_(filters, newfilter)`. Same for arrayFilter, don't append the and, and the and. Just in case, `*` unpacks the whole iterator. In your case, or_ takes two arguments, and your list had 3 when you tried unpacking it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import `or_` from sqlalchemy instead of operators:

```
from sqlalchemy import or_
```